# Getting error 404 when accessing my web application on another devices

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to access my web application on others devices but when i click the login button it gives me a 404 error - the page doesnt exist.
On my computer works fine but in others i get that error.

I've check capital errors on the controllers names but it all seems to be fine.

Anyone have any idea on what it might be?

Config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/CodeIgniter/mponto/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

htaccess file:

```
   DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Pages';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['login'] = 'Utilizador/login';
```

Comment: probably it's your base_url config, which on production server would normally look like: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/CodeIgniter/mponto/'
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://#yourdomain.xxx/CodeIgniter/mponto/'
```

and you should use route default controller for your login not pages

i dont know it will work or not , i am newbie

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$config['is_https'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? true : false;

$config['base_url'] = 'http'.(($config['is_https']) ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/');
```

or

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/CodeIgniter/mponto/';
```

or

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://Yourdomainname/CodeIgniter/mponto/';
```

Comment: it is not working, just works on some computer but in others dont

Answer (score 0):

You can just change base_url in config file.

$config['base_url']='http://base_url/path';